# Erro ao encontrar diretorio .handlebars

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js, nodemailer

Tenho a seguinte estrutura de pastas e arquivos no meu projeto Node:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E a seguinte configuração dos templates de emails:

```
configureTemplates() {
    const viewPath = resolve(__dirname, '..', 'app', 'views', 'emails');

    this.transporter.use('compile', nodemailerhbs({
      viewEngine: exphbs.create({
        layoutsDir: resolve(viewPath, 'layouts'),
        partialsDir: resolve(viewPath, 'partials'),
        defaultLayout: 'default',
        extName: '.hbs',
      }),
      viewPath,
      extName: '.hbs',
    }));
  }
```

Quando executo o método, o seguinte erro é exibido pra mim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que está errado ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Descobri o problema. A propriedade `extname` de dentro do método `create`, é escrita toda minúscula. Apenas a propriedade `extName` do método `use` é escrita com a letra N em maiúsculo.

```
configureTemplates() {
    const viewPath = resolve(__dirname, '..', 'app', 'views', 'emails');

    this.transporter.use('compile', nodemailerhbs({
      viewEngine: exphbs.create({
        layoutsDir: resolve(viewPath, 'layouts'),
        partialsDir: resolve(viewPath, 'partials'),
        defaultLayout: 'default',
        extname: '.hbs',
      }),
      viewPath,
      extName: '.hbs',
    }));
  }
```